# Discord.js PermissionsBitField.Flags

Tags: javascript

Is there a site where I can learn the PermissionsBitField.Flags commands? I want "Guilds and Guilds_messages" flags but I can't find them.

PermissionsBitField.Flags.Guilds and PermissionsBitField.Flags.GuildsMessages is not working???

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The official documentation for the `PermissionsBitField` flags is contained on https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/permissions#permissions-bitwise-permission-flags. I would need more details to understand what specifically isn't work.